# Редактор кода для совместного редактирования кода через интернет?

Tags: php, ide, rust

но обязательно НЕ онлайн сервис. 
языки разработки php и rust.

p.s. в гугле вопрос совсем не ищется.

p.p.s. ОТВЕТА на данный момент НЕ СУЩЕСТВУЕТ, уважаемые пользователи, напишите список из возможных текстовых редакторов, с совместным редактированием кода, назначу лучший ответ.

Comment: Что значит через интернет и не онлайн сервис? p2p? Так то любой текстовый редактор и гитхаб позволяют совместно редактировать код через интернет

Comment: 1. находимся в разных городах, желательно через интернет :) можно и лан и впн... но хотелось бы сразу директ соединение.
2. можно p2p , можно с сервером, но серверную часть обязательно ставить на свой сервер (а-ля nextcloud)
3. пошагово да, а меня интересует онлайн. Примером служит гугл докс

p.s. не сервис значит Codepen.io  не прокатывает

Comment: вот вы абсолютно не по теме ответили/прокомментировали.  Мне сейчас вам пояснять что это не метода для офиса ? что это "парное программирование"? и что альтернатива "один шарит изображение с монитора" второй только смотрит ?  либо вот такой вариант.   Когда составляли ТЗ, План, описание структуры СУБД, то гугл докс весьма интересно себя проявил.  Очень хотелось бы нечто такое для программирования. Как альтернатива еще одна: один пушит изменения на сервер (без гита, просто тупо довнлоад после сейва)  после нескольких строк, а второй их так же принимает.  вот это самый отстойный вариант.

Comment: Знаю только единственный вариант, когда можно редактировать файл одновременно - гугл документы. Там это можно. Удобно для составления документации. Но вот для кода ... не представляю, в чем ценность.

Comment: @Majestio для кода - ценность в возможности удаленной отладки. В Visual Studio такое есть, причем между разными IDE (VS / VS Code) и между разными платформами - https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/services/live-share/. Правда, через сервера MS, так что топикастеру не подойдет.

Comment: @PashaPash да вы правы, всё было бы хорошо, если бы M$ не было посередине.

Comment: @DevAzmandios т.е. гугл, в котором вы документацию вели - ок, а MS - внезапно, не ок? :)

Comment: @PashaPash в яблочко ) одно дело магазинчик для клиента, с некоторыми интересными фишками.  И совсем совсем другое , свой совместный проект

Comment: @DevAzmandios на MS сидит такое количество корпораций, включая госконторы US, что любой намек на доступ к вашему коду со стороны сотрудников MS будет диким скандалом. Я очень сомневаюсь, что ради вашего личного проекта MS (или гугл, или атлассиан) рискнут всем и поставят под угрозу свое существование.

Comment: @PashaPash у них закрытые продукты, вот внезапно появится аналог моего творения с моим алгоритмом, и тут уж я ничего доказать не смогу ))  а во всём остальном вы безусловно правы.  Корпорации это акулы, и относится нужно к ним соответственно.

Comment: редактор для совместной работы с кодом называется Git, ни чего лучше системы контроля версий для этого не придумали

Comment: прокоментировали не читая предыдущих коментов (